# Stirling number equality

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How to prove that $\left\{{n}\atop{k}\right\} = \sum_{i_1,\ldots,i_{n-k}}i_1\cdot i_2\dots i_{n-k} \cdot [1\le i_1\le i_2 \le \ldots \le i_{n-k}\le k]\ $ and $\left[{n}\atop{k}\right] = \sum_{i_1,\ldots,i_{n-k}}i_1\cdot i_2\dots i_{n-k} \cdot [0< i_1 < i_2 < \ldots < i_{n-k} < n]$? Sorry but I don't know even how to begin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: The Stirling numbers of the second satisfy the recurrence

$${{n+1}\brace k}=k{n\brace k}+{n\brace{k-1}}\;.$$

Let

$$f(n,k)=\sum_{i_1,\ldots,i_{n-k}}[1\le i_1\le\ldots\le i_{n-k}\le k]\prod_{j=1}^{n-k}i_j\;;$$

the idea is to show that $f(n,k)$ satisfies the recurrence

$$f(n+1,k)=kf(n,k)+f(n,k-1)$$

with the same initial values. The products $\prod_{j=1}^{(n+1)-k}i_j$ with $1\le i_1\le\ldots\le i_{(n+1)-k}\le k$ can be split into two sets: those with $i_{(n+1)-k}=k$, and those with $i_{(n+1)-k}<k$.

- Show that the sum of the products in the first set is $kf(n,k)$.
- Show that the sum of the products in the second set is $f(n,k-1)$.
- Check the initial values.

For the other part of the problem, recall that the Stirling numbers of the first kind satisfy the recurrence

$${{n+1}\brack k}=n{n\brack k}+{n\brack{k+1}}\;.$$